# Same commits between two branch after merge

Tags: git, github, branch, git-cherry-pick

I have two branches `devel` and `next`. In `devel` I have a more or less huge amount of commits. Some of the commits are cherry picked into next. Also I added some commits to next and I have commits which are merged from `devel`.

Now I would like to see which commit is missing in next from `devel`, so I can cherry-pick the missed commit to next. My question is now,

How to check same commits between the `devl` and `next`
The commits from `devel` is there or not in `next`?
If not there I would have to cherry-pick to `next`.

Comment: You have a potential problem here, because when you cherry picked those commits from `devel` to `next`, Git assigned a new SHA-1 hash to them.  This means that you can't simply compare hashes to answer your question.  Maybe the best solution long term for your problem would be to develop a better Git workflow.

Comment: Once you get `next` to the state you want (i.e. once it has everything in `devel`), I would do a `git merge -s ours devel`. This will let git know that all the changes have been moved over. Then from now on, just merge from `devel` to `next`, don't cherry pick.

Answer (score 1):

You want the cherry-pick-related options [git log](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) has, one of `--cherry-mark`, `--cherry-pick`:

```
git log --cherry-mark next...devel        # <-- three dots, not two, for symmetric diff.
```

Do note that any text-diff-based solution can be fooled here, and avoiding even the off chance is one of the reasons to do only recorded merges in published work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
git log devel..next
```

This will show you commits that devel has but not in next